# How to display an image next to a menu item?

Tags: python, image, pygtk, menuitem

I am trying to get an image to appear next to a menu item but it isn't working.

In order to make this as simple as possible, I have created a very simple example below that highlights the problem:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class MenuExample:

    def __init__(self):

        window = gtk.Window()
        window.set_size_request(200, 100)
        window.connect("delete_event", lambda w,e: gtk.main_quit())

        menu = gtk.Menu()

        menu_item = gtk.ImageMenuItem("Refresh")

        img = gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_REFRESH, gtk.ICON_SIZE_MENU)
        img.show()
        menu_item.set_image(img)

        menu.append(menu_item)

        menu_item.show()

        root_menu = gtk.MenuItem("File")

        root_menu.show()
        root_menu.set_submenu(menu)

        vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        window.add(vbox)
        vbox.show()

        menu_bar = gtk.MenuBar()
        vbox.pack_start(menu_bar, False, False, 2)
        menu_bar.show()

        menu_bar.append(root_menu)

        window.show()

def main():
    gtk.main()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MenuExample()
    main()
```

When I run the application, it shows the menu item, but it does not show the image next to it.

**OS:** Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit
**Python version:** 2.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... it turns out the answer was that my desktop theme had disabled icons for menus. (Who *knows* why.)

After enabling the option, the icons now show up.

Comment: You should accept your answer -- after all, it did answer the question!

Comment: @kat: I can't accept my own answer until 48 hours after I posted it.

Comment: sorry, I forgot about that! =)

Comment: This is the default in Gnome these days.